# Множественное наследование интерфейса

Tags: c++, наследование, интерфейс, агрегация

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
class IChunk
{
    public;
    virtual void Method() = 0;
};

class FlatChunk : public IChunk
{
    public:
    void Method() override;
};

class IAudioChunk : public IChunk
{
    public:
    virtual AudioFormat GetFormat() const = 0;
};

class IVideoChunk : public IChunk
{
    public:
    virtual VideoFormat GetFormat() const = 0;
};

class SomeAudioChunk : public IAudioChunk, public FlatChunk
{
    public:
    AudioFormat GetFormat() const override;
};

class SomeVideoChunk : public IVideoChunk, public FlatCHunk,
{
    public:
    VideoFormat GetFormat() const override;
};
```

Это упрощенный код.

Здесь должно происходить следующее:

- `IChunk` - это интерфейс для работы с каким-то куском данных;
- `FlatChunk` - реализация интерфейса `IChunk`, которая работает с данными, хранящимися в памяти в виде сплошного массива байтов;
- `IAudioChunk` - интерфейс для работы с аудиоданными, который наследуется от интерфейса работы с данными, плюс еще кое-что, специфичное для аудио;
- `IVideoChunk` - интерфейс для работы с видеоданными, который наследуется от интерфейса работы с данными, плюс еще кое-что, специфичное для видео;
- `SomeAudioChunk` - какая-то реализация интерфейса `IAudioChunk`, которая, к тому же, использует реализацию `FlatChunk` для работы с данными в виде сплошной последовательности байтов;
- `SomeVideoChunk` - какая-то реализация интерфейса `IVideoChunk`, которая, к тому же, использует реализацию `FlatChunk` для работы с данными в виде сплошной последовательности байтов.

В этом коде есть несколько вещей (запахов), которые меня смущают, поэтому при реализации проекта, в котором возникла аналогичная ситуация, я использовал композицию/агрегацию, вместо наследования.

Например, так:

```
class IAudioChunk
{
    public:
    virtual IChunk* GetChunk() = 0;
    virtual AudioFormat GetFormat() const = 0;
};
```

Но я бы хотел обсудить изначальную задумку.

Итак, проблемы первоначального кода заключаются в следующем:

1) `SomeAudioChunk` и `SomeVideoChunk` наследуют интерфейс `IChunk` дважды.

- Во-первых, мне не ясно: можно ли наследоваться от интерфейса и от реализации интерфейса без использования виртуального наследования?
- Во-вторых: потенциальные мысли о необходимости использования в коде виртуального наследования - это запах и повод серьезно задуматься над архитектурой;
- В-третьих: имеет ли значение, в каком порядке происходит наследование от интерфейса и от его реализации?

2) Я не уверен, что между типами `IChunk` и `IAudioChunk`, а также между типами `IChunk` и `IVideoChunk`, - существует отношение `is a` (является). На мой взгляд, `has a` в данной ситуации более уместно.

Доводы следующие:

- Если `IAudioChunk` и `IVideoChunk` наследовать от `IChunk` (отношение `is a`), тогда при реализации `SomeAudioChunk` и `SomeVideoChunk` нужно как-то и откуда-то брать реализацию интерфейса `IChunk`; брать ее наследованием от `FlatChunk` - сомнительный процесс, а писать в ручную - глупо;
- Если для `IAudioChunk` и `IVideoChunk` использовать композицию/агрегацию, тогда все наследники данных классов не будут зависеть от реализации `FlatChunk`,  и даже смогут менять эту реализацию в процессе выполнения, и это очень даже хорошо, гибко, понятно и удобно.

Я хочу найти ответы на свои вопросы. В книгах найти их мне не удалось.

Comment: а вы в курсе, что  в вашей иерархии SomeAudioChunk и SomeVideoChunk  все еще являются абстрактными классами?

Comment: Нет, потому что я не понимаю, что происходит при наследовании и от интерфейса, и от его реализации.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала напишу как я сделал бы:

```
class IChunk
{
public:
    virtual void Method() = 0;
};

class FlatChunk :  public IChunk
{
public:
    void Method() override;
};

class IAudioChunk : virtual  public FlatChunk
{
public:
    virtual AudioFormat GetFormat() const = 0;
};

class IVideoChunk : virtual  public FlatChunk
{
public:
    virtual VideoFormat GetFormat() const = 0;
};

class SomeAudioChunk : public IAudioChunk
{
public:    
    AudioFormat GetFormat() const override;
};

class SomeVideoChunk : public IVideoChunk
{
    public:
    VideoFormat GetFormat() const override;
};
```

Потому что `class FlatChunk` уже содержит в себе весь интерфейс `IChunk` и определение всех или некоторых функций. Т.е. FlatChunk становится узловым классом для  остальной иерархии, и он может быть или не быть абстрактным классом(это вам решать). Но как конкретно подойти к вопросу(использование, агрегация или наследование(открытое или закрытое), обо всем этом нужно еще подумать и пообсуждать)

В вашей реализации, например  `SomeAudioChunk`, имеет все что есть в `IAudioChunk` и `FlatChunk`, а значит имеет все виртуальные методы и замещанные методы обеих классов. Т.е. он имеет два чистых виртуальных функции и одну определенную `FlatChunk::Method`. Т.е. ваши целевые классы  в вашей реализации являются узловыми, а не целевыми. Теперь ответы на ваши вопросы, думаю проясняются, но, если нужно, отвечу конкретно на конкретные вопросы.

1. Да, наследование происходит дважды(это никчему)

   - Да, можно наследовать и интерфейсный класс и класс реализации(но не
     знаю когда это может понадобится)
   - Над архитектурой по любому нужно серьезно задуматься. Виртуальное
   - наследование всего лишь инструмент наследовать от одного и того же
     обьекта, оно ничего не усложняет.
   - Нет
2. Если наследование открытое, то существует отношение `is a`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Проблема в том, что `IAudioChunk` - это интерфейс, а не абстрактный класс, и он не должен базироваться на реализации `FlatChunk`.

Comment: @MGNeo, я не понел что вы имеете ввиду. Абстрактные классы и есть интерфейсные классы.  Вы хотите,  к интерфейсу  IAudioChunk добавить и интерфейс  IChunk и  этот суммарный интерфейс и FlatChunk использовать для определения целевых классов, вот и пускай  IAudioChunk базируется на  FlatChunk, что  вас смущает?

Comment: Вы хотите в  ящик засунуть  упаковку  в котором находится  мешок и коробка, в которой находится такой же мешок, , однако вам не нужны два мешка в ящике. Я вам предлагаю (грубо говоря)засунуть  коробку (где находится мешок), в упаковку, а упаковку в ящик.

Comment: Вы смешиваете понятия абстрактного класса и интерфейса. Интерфейс не должен содержать ничего, кроме чисто виртуальных методов. Тем более, интерфейс не должен наследовать реализацию.

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы `SomeAudioChunk` и `SomeVideoChunk` использовали уже существующую реализацию интерфейса `IChunk`, но я не хочу, чтобы все наследники `IAudioChunk` и `IVideoChunk` использовали реализацию `FlatChunk` .

Comment: Еще раз, абстрактные классы есть интерфейсные классы. Если вы хотите, чтобы ваши абстрактные классы были только интерфейсом (вам важно это больше, чем решение задачи), значит нужно  строить иерархию совсем по другому,  Вопрос архитектуры зависит от контеста, от многих хочу и не хочу, нужно или не нужно.  И,  может быть,   наследование не лучший способ  реализации всех классов. Насколько они логически жестко должны быть связаны и как, решаются при полной информации о задаче и  после полного анализа.

Comment: В любом случаи ваше решение точно неправильное, На подобный вопрос нет однозначного ответа, я лишь пытался вам помочь, хоть и вы никогда ответы не принимаете.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105557/discussion-between-ar-hovsepyan-and-mgneo).